# How to use my laptop screen for raspberry pi 4

Tags: linux, laptop, display, raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry pi 4 with a Noobs pre-installed sd card(so I don't want to mess around with it much). I wanted to use my laptop screen for the raspberry pi and I am not sure what is the easiest and best way to do this as the internet has a lot of methods. Can someone help me out of this situation, any help is much appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: Better asked on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to enable the VNC server on the Raspberry Pi. We do not know what kind of laptop you have (Windows, Mac, Slackware, etc.), but there should be a VNC viewer available for your laptop.

On the Pi, use `raspi-config` to enable the VNC server. Make sure that you change the resolution (do NOT keep it on the default)